# Google play store reviews images not loading in firefox

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to display google play store reviews on my site. I used the reviewer images by directly using their images link. Which worked fine in chrome. However, it's not coming at all in Firefox. If I try to download the images from firefox, it's getting downloaded. Don't know what's the issue with firefox.

Try this fiddle in chrome and firefox.[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sourabhgarg/ge5xsjwh/)

```
<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-lOc7QT4r0fg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABSg/0Ll7k0KSnss/w48-c-h48-rw/photo.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove -rw from your link and it should be fine in firefox and other non-chrome based browsers:

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-lOc7QT4r0fg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABSg/0Ll7k0KSnss/w48-c-h48/photo.jpg